# str_replace infected code with a wildcard

Tags: php, regex

I have a website that has been infected with malware code, heres an example:

```
<?php if(!isset($GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"])) { $ua=strto...algiyujsz-1; ?>
```

It's a rather large code, however I'm guessing due to some characters str_replace is not working, how would I go about replacing a string like the above via preg_replace(the ... being a wildcard)? I'm rather bad at regex and can't get it working. Or is there some way to get this working via str_replace so I have a point of reference for furure?

Full code here: http://pastie.org/10084259

Thank you!

Comment: You should remove the infected code and patch security holes. Using str_replace is a really bad solution.

Comment: Id suggest that if your site has been compromised then the only real safe action is to wipe the server and redeploy it. If they could insert add files then you don't know the extent to which they have compromoised your server.

Comment: What do you think i'm using str_replace for? For a PHP script to scan the files so the code gets removed.

Comment: I'm asking how to remove it, not how to handle the security, I need to remove the code before i can patch it and redeploy it.

Comment: @SauliusAntanavicius I think Frank  means it better to look with your own eyes and remove the code, to make sure you deleted everything and not just trust `str_replace()`. Also it would be very hard to define a pattern only for the malware code! (Seems like there are some sites getting hacked. This is like the 5 Q in the last 2 days about sites getting hacked and infected)

Comment: It's been added via same type of script, it's inserted at 0 characters in every php file, seeing as I have thousands of files, doing it by hand is not an option.

Comment: I'm guessing that you haven't made a backup?

Comment: Well you always learn it in the university/school: Make a backup kids! (But there are some students which then are sitting there after 5 months of project time with nothing in their project folder, because someone deleted it and they don't have a backup!)

Comment: Christ sake, first of all it's not for me it's for a client, second of all, commenting here with things like that is not what i'm after.

Comment: Well I think if you (the client) don't have a backup, there will be NO way around it, just to check all files to be 100% sure that all malicious code is gone! So even if you do a `str_replace()` you still have to check it if everything is gone. You also then have the "issue" that you don't know to 100% if `str_replace()` also deleted part of the website itself

Comment: you want a regex to tell legal code from obfuscated malware code. unless it's always the same chunk inserted in different places I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Code is identical on all files, thats the thing. So thats why I'm asking for regex expression, this is done via automatic script that inserted the code into every php file, thats why I only need to scan through all the .php files and do a replace.

Comment: _“Code is identical on all files, thats the thing. So thats why I'm asking for regex expression”_ – why would you need a regular expression, if the text to search for is _static_? And you’re aware that `str_replace`, as mentioned by you in question title, does _not_ use regular expressions, right …? (Anyway, with your attitude you might want to bookmark whatever “solution” you come up with here … because you will likely be using it again shortly … and again …)

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue with `'/<\?php if\(!isset\(\$GL(.+?)z-1; \?>/is'` and preg_replace